# US visa process for medical graduate

Tags: usa, visa, education, medical

The case is as follows:

- Physician with EU citizenship.
- Cardiology training completed in the EU, never worked in the US.
- Interest in pursuing a medical fellowship in the US with several options to choose from.
- ECFMG exams completed, certificate to be delivered soon.
- USMLE Step 3 not taken yet.

Questions:

1. Can the candidate already start the visa application process even though USMLE Step 3 is not done yet? Apparently, this last step seems required in some States.
2. If some fellowship positions are not ACGME accredited, what options does the candidate have at the end of their training should they wish to stay in the US?

If this SE is not the right place to ask, thanks for advising a more suitable community; cheers.